# Updating of photo in upload directory not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem in my script to update photo. when i upload a photo to update a particular user, it updates all the user in the mysql table with the photo i uploaded with out renaming it with the `staff_id`.

According to my script it suppose to rename the photo with the `staff_id`, updates it to the user and overwrite any photo of that user in upload directory. please what am i doing wrong, my snippet is below:

```
<?php
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.pdf','.xlsx','.xls','.doc','.docx','.ppt','.pptx','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.pdf');
   $max_filesize = 52428800; // max file size = 50MB
   $target = "images/"; 
   $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
 // get form data, making sure it is valid and also sanitize the inputs

 $pic = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_FILES['photo']['name']));

  //This gets all the other information from the form

$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $file = $_FILES['photo']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
    $ext = substr($file, strpos($file,'.'), strlen($file)-1);
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))//check if file type is allowed
        die('The file extension you attempted to upload is not allowed.'); //not allowed
    if(filesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) //check that filesize is less than 50MB
        die ('The file you attempted to upload is too large, compress it below 50MB.');


   // Connects to your Database
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
     mysql_select_db("office") or die(mysql_error()) ;


$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


$uploaddir = 'images/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

echo "<p>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

//Writes the information to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' ");
 $uploaddir = "images/" .mysql_insert_id() . $ext;  
 $staff_id = mysql_insert_id();
  $new_file_name = mysql_insert_id() . $ext;

  //I removed ,photo='$target' to display only id as picture name
  mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$new_file_name' WHERE staff_id=$staff_id");

echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

} else {

   echo "Upload failed";

}
echo "</p>";

echo '<pre>';

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';

print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Rollback from edit that should never been approved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read your code?

You actually run

```
mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' ");
```

And then a few lines below, you run

```
$staff_id = mysql_insert_id();
$new_file_name = mysql_insert_id() . $ext;
mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$new_file_name' WHERE staff_id=$staff_id");
```

The first query will obviously do what you mention as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' ");
```

you should have a `WHERE` clause for the `staff_id` like (and to all your update queries)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' WHERE staff_id = ".$staff_id);
```

---

* Note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Here's the mysqli_ equivalent of your query:

```
$query = "UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' WHERE staff_id = ".$staff_id

$link = mysqli_connect("[your_host]","[your_user]","[password]","[database]") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$result = $link->query($query);
```

Comment: i used this code mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' WHERE staff_id = ".$staff_id); but its giving error Notice: Undefined variable: staff_id how do i define it since my upload is only sending the photo only? from the form

Comment: Yes on your last query but not on the first one. Have you seen it?

Comment: Ok, now how do you determine the value or the current staff that edit the picture? You can put that staff's id in `$staff_id` variable.

Comment: how do i define staff_id  since my upload is only sending the photo only? from the form to the upload.php

Comment: How do you login your user? or staff? Or how do you store the current user? I assume you knew about sessions? If you store the user_id in a session, it is easier for you to edit this. Now if you are an admin and you have the right to edit the picture you can store the id of the 'selected' staff.

Comment: the stafff_id is an id with auto increment in mysql, i didnt use session its a simple app where admin can just add staff info and be able to edit it. the only charlenge i have now is define the staff_id to work

Comment: Yes. You can put them in a `<input type="hidden">` and get them on post.

Comment: this is what i did <input type="hidden" id="staff_id" name="staff_id" > i dont know if am wrong correct me

Comment: Where is the value? You have to include those. `value="$row['staff_id']"` when displaying. Then on your submit, get the staff_id by `$_POST['staff_id']`

Comment: am still having problem geting the staff_if here is my trigger <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="change_photo.php"  name="myform" id="myform" method="POST"> 
 <input type="hidden" id="staff_id" name="staff_id" value="$row['staff_id']" />
       <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">

Comment: and here is the code $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$staff_id = $_POST['staff_id'];


$uploaddir = 'images/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

echo "<p>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' WHERE staff_id='$staff_id' ");

Answer (score 0):

You are first updating the whole Table??? WHY???

your this code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$pic' ");
```

is actually updating it.

I think you need to refine your code.

Also Checking file only on the extension is not good, you can be fooled by adding wrong extensions to the file.

EDIT:

You need to get the staff_id from the page, from where you getting request to update the photo, or else you must have it in your session or something(as i dont know how its working).

Using that staff_if jus add the WHERE clause.

And i dont know what these 2 update statements doing in your code?

Comment: Yes its updating the whole table but i want to refine my code with the where clause to modify only a specific user

Comment: You know the staff ID to update??, if yes just add it in WHERE clause.